# Splunk: Is there a way to remove the Clone dashboard option

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I need a way to stop users with access to a Studio dashboard from being able to clone it.

From this they are able to edit this new dashboard, giving these particular user too much access.
These users having a minimal amount of role capabilities, Search and List all objects. So I'm unable to give them any less capabilities. (not that any seem to relate to this.)

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image: Cloned here]

[image: Cloned here 2]

[image: Can open Dashboard after creation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you export the data outside Splunk, anyone can clone a Dashboard (perhaps only to their own private view, but clone it nonetheless)

If they're not supposed to have access to various data sources, you need to restrict their access to those sourcetype(s) or index(es)

Comment: Dashboards are not security devices.  The only way to secure data is by restricting the index(es) a role can access.

Comment: unfortunate, ty for your input guys, this was what I was expecting but also hoping not to hear.

Comment: @DanielPrice - I understand the desire to hide what's going on underneath the hood, but the way to do that is to ship results out of Splunk (or, sometimes, make the panels of a Dashboard dependent upon scheduled Reports that run under a different user).